# Issue with Content Over Navbar - Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have some slight styling issue with my HTML/CSS code over my navbar.

Here's what it looks like right now.

[image]

And here's what I want it to look like:

[image]

Here's my HTML code for that bit:

```
<div class="page">
  <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="col-xs-10 col-sm-3 branding">
          <a class="imgCon" href="{{var protoHost}}">
              <img alt="Coolguy" src="{{var protoHost}}img/coolguy.png">
          </a>
      </div>
      <div class="container-fluid ContactNumber col-xs-0">
        <p><i class="fa fa-phone"></i><a href="tel:555-555-5555" style="color: black"> 555-555-5555</a></p>
        <p><i class="fa fa-envelope"><a href="info@coolguy.co" style="color: black"></i> info@coolguy.co</a></p>
      </div>
      <div class="container-fluid ContactNumber">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">My Account</button>
      </div>
```

And my CSS:

```
html{
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
}
body{
    font-family: "Roboto";
    margin-bottom: 60px;
}
a{
    color:#00A0F0;
}
.spacer{
    height:70px;
    width: 100%;
}
.socialspacer {
  height: 30px;
}
.AccountButton {
  padding-left: 730px;
}
.smallspacer{
  height: 35px;
  width: 100%;
}
.spacer-1{width:100%;height:10px;}.spacer-2{width:100%;height:20px;}.spacer-3{width:100%;height:30px;}.spacer-4{width:100%;height:40px;}
.spacer-5{width:100%;height:50px;}.spacer-6{width:100%;height:60px;}.spacer-7{width:100%;height:70px;}.spacer-8{width:100%;height:80px;}
.spacer-9{width:100%;height:90px;}.spacer-10{width:100%;height:100px;}.spacer-11{width:100%;height:110px;}.spacer-12{width:100%;height:120px;}

.locationTitle{
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: 700;
    font-size: 2em;
    color:#007dd1;
    margin-bottom: 24px;
    margin-left: 24px;
    margin-top: 24px;
}
.subTitle{
    text-align: center;
}
.subHead{
    line-height: 1em;
    font-size: .6em;
}
.navbar{
    height: 100px;
    background-color:
}
.navbar>.container-fluid{
    height: 100px;
    padding: 0;
}
.navbar>.container-fluid>*{
    height: 100px;
}
.navbar>.container-fluid img{
    height: 100px;
}
.branding *{
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    color: #007dd1
}
.navbartext p  {
      padding-top: 17px;
      padding-left: 172px;
      text-align: center;
      font-size: 17px;
}
.ContactNumber  {
  padding-top: 38px;
}
.contactspacer {
  margin-top: 45px;
}
.InternetSpacer {
  height: 45px;
}
.InfoSpacer {
  margin-left: 45px;
}
.centerlinks {
  text-align: center;
}
.navIcon{
    padding: 10px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    color:white;
    background-color: #0071bd;
}
.navbar > li > a:hover{
    text-shadow: 0 1px 3px #CDF;
}
.navbar li:not(.navSep):hover{
    margin: 0 0 -2px 0;
    border-bottom: 2px solid white;
}

.navSep{
    width:2px;
    height: 40px;
    margin: 5px 2px 5px 2px;
    background-color: #A9AFDD;
}

.imgCon{
    max-height: 100%;
    max-width:100%;

}
.imgCon img{
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    max-width:100%;
    max-height: 100%;
        padding-bottom: 25px;
}

.page{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    padding-bottom:50px;
}

@media (max-width:768px){
    div[aria-expanded="true"] .navSep{
        display: none;
    }
}

.mainTitle{
    font-size: 1.5em;
    font-weight: 700;
    background-color: white;
}

.extraInfo{
    background-color: #333;
    color:white;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 2px 1px grey;
    font-size: 1.2em;
}

.footer{
  background-color: #007dd1;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 110px;
  text-align: right;
}
.footer a{
    text-align: center;
    height: 100%;
    color: white;
}
.footer p{
    text-align: center;
    height: 100%;
    color: white;
}
@media (min-width : 1200px) {
    .col-xl-0{display:none;}

}
@media (max-width : 1200px){
    .col-lg-0{display:none;}
}
@media (max-width : 992px){
    .col-md-0{display:none;}
}
@media (max-width : 768px){
    .col-sm-0{display:none;}
}
@media (max-width : 480px){
    .col-xs-0{display:none;}
    .page {
      padding-bottom: 160px;
    }
    .footer {
      height: 160px;
    }
}



@font-face {
  font-family: 'Roboto';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: local('Roboto'), local('Roboto-Regular'), url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v15/CWB0XYA8bzo0kSThX0UTuA.woff2) format('woff2');
}
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Roboto';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 700;
  src: local('Roboto Bold'), local('Roboto-Bold'), url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v15/d-6IYplOFocCacKzxwXSOFtXRa8TVwTICgirnJhmVJw.woff2) format('woff2');
}
```

Any ideas/suggestions would be great!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is due to placing your data into block level elements...the `<p>` and `<div>` tags.

If you want the contact data to display inline, you can give the `<p>` a class and style it to display inline, or you can place both into the same `<p>` tag.

```
<p class="inlineParagraph"><i class="fa fa-phone"></i><a href="tel:555-555-5555" style="color: black"> 555-555-5555</a></p>
<p class="inlineParagraph"><i class="fa fa-envelope"><a href="info@coolguy.co" style="color: black"></i> info@coolguy.co</a></p>
<div class="clear"></div>

.inlineParagraph {
  float:left;
  display:inline;
}
.clear {
  clear:both;
}
```

Or...

```
<p><span class="contactInfo"><i class="fa fa-phone"></i><a href="tel:555-555-5555" style="color: black"> 555-555-5555</a></span>
<span class="contactInfo"><i class="fa fa-envelope"><a href="info@coolguy.co" style="color: black"></i> info@coolguy.co</a></span></p>
```

and style your span class with whatever spacing you need.

As far as the "My Account" button, that is also having the same problem. It is in a block level element. You can add float and inline display to the div as well to correct this issue and it will display as you want it to.

Sorry for the lack of code outlining how to set up your layout correctly. I am currently on my phone and coding on this thing is less than ideal! If you need more direction on this, I can update my answer with code when I get back to a computer.

===EDIT===

Here is some updated HTML and CSS that I have applied in a Fiddle...

```
<div class="page">
  <div class="container-fluid">
  <!-- id 'tempStyle' added to create artificial boundry for testing -->
      <div id="tempStyle" class="col-xs-10 col-sm-3 branding">
          <a class="imgCon" href="{{var protoHost}}">
          Image goes here
             <!-- <img alt="Coolguy" src="{{var protoHost}}img/coolguy.png">-->
          </a>
      </div>
      <div class="container-fluid ContactNumber col-xs-0">
        <p class="inlineParagraph"><i class="fa fa-phone"></i><a href="tel:555-555-5555" style="color: black"> 555-555-5555</a></p>
<p class="inlineParagraph"><i class="fa fa-envelope"><a href="info@coolguy.co" style="color: black"></i> info@coolguy.co</a></p>
<div class="clear"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="container-fluid ContactNumber">
        <button id="myAccountBtn" type="button" class="btn btn-primary">My Account</button>
      </div>
      <!-- 'Clearing' floated divs to prevent breaking content further down the tree -->
      <div class="clear"></div>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Some of your CSS was also modified a bit. It is all in the Fiddle but here is an example of what I did:

```
.ContactNumber  {
  padding-top: 38px;
  float:left;
  display:inline;
  width: 275px;
}
```

The width was added to allow inline display on the Fiddle. You will probably have to adjust it to your specific needs.

Fiddle link: https://jsfiddle.net/vwzg7rxt/

Comment: That fixed it!  Thanks SO much!

Comment: If you could update for my button, that would be great.  Thanks.

Comment: I have updated my answer with a fiddle link and more code for clarity. If you have any other questions, I will be happy to answer them.

Comment: Thanks for the code, but I figured it out!  I just Googled block level elements and realized my issue was in one of my Div tags.  Thanks for all the help, though!